# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' con mysql en kubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Acabo de hacer una instalación limpia de mySQL en Kubuntu 20.04 (me imagino que el problema será el mismo con otros derivados de Ubuntu).

Al intentar firmarme en la base de datos para crear una base de datos para mi proyecto, obtengo:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

El password está vacío, porque no he "asegurado" mi ambiente (ni me interesa por ser mi server de desarrollo al que solo yo tengo acceso). El caso es que si hago lo mismo con `sudo`, no hay problema:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter Password:
...
mysql>
```

Como ya me funciona, no tengo problema, cree mi base de datos y ya funciona todo. Lo que tengo es curiosidad ¿qué es lo que tendría que hacer para acceder al usuario root desde cualquier cuenta? Obviamente por esta pregunta habrán descubierto que la mayor parte de mi desarrollo lo hago en Windows.

Comment: En linux se hace justo como lo describes (usando sudo), en windows simplemente debes ejecutar como admin la terminal,  aunque creo que en windows esto es un poco mas flexible,  al punto que incluso hasta sea innecesario ejecutarlo como administrador, eso fue lo que te entendi con la pregunta,  si tu pregunta es mas bien como acceder en ambos sistemas operativos a la misma base de datos no se puede,  porque la arquitectura de los sistemas difiere,  y si bien puedes importar la base de datos en ambos sistemas,  los datos no seran actualizados en ambos.

Comment: Exacto, en Windows no es necesario acceder a mysql como administrador. Lo que quería saber es si hay alguna forma de configurarlo para que sea como Windows, por pura curiosidad. Insisto, no tengo problema con usar cuatro letras más, pero es pura curiosidad por entender las diferencias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En `linux`, por defecto, solo el usuario `root` necesita utilizar `sudo`, lo que podes hacer es:

#### Opción 1:

Crear otro usuario

```
mysql > CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

---

#### Opción 2:

Cambiar el algoritmo:

```
mysql > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Gracias, quería hacer lo segundo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Siempre al instalar y configurar mysql se debe de ejecutar el siguiente comando

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Escogemos el nivel de seguridad de la contraseña, luego ponemos la contraseña que cumpla con esos requisitos, confirmamos. Después decimos si (`Y`) a todo.

Ahora entramos a MySQL.

```
sudo mysql
```

Y ejecutamos:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Cambiamos `password` por la contraseña que configuramos.

Salimos de MySQL, reiniciamos el servicio y ahora podemos entrar con root y nuestra nueva contraseña.